# How to get rid of "What's new in Thunderbird 3.1" starting tab

Tags: thunderbird

How do I get rid of "What's new in Thunderbird 3.1" tab, which appears when starting Thunderbird?

Answer (score 3):

- Go into **Tools > Options**
- Make sure you are in the *General* tab
- Uncheck the box labelled:
  **When Thunderbird launches, show the Start Page in the message area**

Comment: I'm running on a Mac, and there is NO Tools -> Options... it's under Preferences, and it already is UN-checked...

Comment: Try setting the location of the start page to about:blank

Comment: @spokane - Register your SU account with same OpenID as on SO to regain control of this question

Answer (score -3):

On Mac OS delete the start page info (yes even if its unchecked). This will fix it.

Comment: Hello, please add any details to your answer. E.g. where to delete it.

Comment: Does this answer actually apply to this more than 10 year old question?

Comment: Caligula, please follow the advice of Destroy666.